# Kill running instances of processes except which is triggered due to current command executed

Tags: linux, shell-script, kill

I've to kill all running instances of Xvfb using shell script hence have following code -

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | awk '/Xvfb/ {print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done
```

It kills all instances but one fails with following error -

```
kill: (142898) - No such process
```

Seems above executed command creates one more instance but which no more exists while killing. In this case, how can I skip that and succeed with the script?

Comment: `pkill Xvfb`? Any reason to make it complicated? And why the `SIGKILL`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are piping the output of `ps` into a call to `awk` that looks for the string "Xvfb" and therefore also contains the string "Xvfb" in its own command-line. Because both processes of a pipe are executed simultanously, the `awk` call itself will also register in the output of `ps` (try what happens if you just type `ps -ef | awk '/Xvfb/'` on the command-line).

However, by the time the loop is started (which happens when the command-substitution `$( … )` and therefore the `awk` process, too, has exited), this `awk` process doesn't exist anymore, hence `kill` stumbles upon this.

You should be safe if you modify the command in the command substitution to

```
ps -ef | awk '$0 ~ /Xvfb/ && index($0,"awk")==0 {print $2}'
```

which will ensure that no command containing the substring `awk` are included in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to kill the `awk`.

A simple regex trick to avoid this is to use some sort of escaping. Such as `wor[d]`.

So for your code (with variable quoting added)

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | awk '/Xvf[b]/ {print $2}'); do kill -9 "$pid"; done
```

Comment: Note that `"$(...)"` is a single string, so the loop is a bit useless.